# Gnuplot 5.0 distortion issue on grid in 3d plot

Tags: plot, 3d, gnuplot

After updating my previous gnuplot installation to the newest version (http://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/files/gnuplot/5.0.0/) 5.0.0 on Windows, I encounter issues with the grid in 3d plots. Take this example:

```
set term png

set grid x, y, z

set isosamples 50, 50

set out 'out.png'

f(x,y) = sin(x) * cos(y)

splot f(x,y) w pm3d palette t ''
```

The result is:

[image: 3d plot from gnuplot 5.0.0 with grid enabled]

The installation was repeated once; the folder was emptied before that to make sure no residual files are left from the previous installation. The problem can be reproduced also when plotting "3d data". Is there anything I'm doing wrong here or is this a bug?

Comment: Uargh, quite ugly. Check, whether the `pngcairo` terminal works. There has been a bug report about this issue for the gif (also libgd) terminal, http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1549/.

Comment: Yes, pngcairo doesn't have this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a bug report about this issue for the gif terminal, see http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1549/. The png terminal also uses the libgd, so this is probably the same bug.

You can use the `pngcairo` terminal, which generally produces better results.

As this bug is related to the specific axis linetype, `linetype 0`, you define your own line type for use with the grid. But then you cannot use dashed lines, which the gd-terminals don't support:

```
set linetype 11 dashtype 2 lc rgb '#bbbbbb'
set grid lt 11
```